# Azure Functions consumption plan and cold start costs

Tags: azure-functions

I'm trying to figure out the best way to have an azure function consumption plan and not have my bill skyrocket. I added a timer function that executes every 10 minutes to keep my functions from cold starting, but by adding this timer function my cost forecast goes up $20-40 every day. Is this normal or is there anything I can do to minimize cost while keeping functions on consumption plan?

Answer (score 1):

I think you calculated wrong.
If you execute a timer trigger function just keeping a instance warm, additional cost is a few dollars per month.

In addition, you can also use Premium plan or App Service to keep warm.

https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale

Comment: I saw something in cost management last night that said v2 premium, but all my function apps were on consumption plans so I don't understand where that was coming from, but I deleted the resource since cost management referenced it when I did ``Group By``` I forget what I set it to, but I guess we'll see if the forecast drops in the next 12 hours